# Ms Access move from one field to other

Tags: database, ms-access

I converted a pdf file to an access one. All of the info got put in one field. I need them in 6 different fields. How can i move them all easily? All are text types.

Comment: How do you conver pdf file (a document) to ms access (database)?

Comment: Is it pdf or mdf? Show some example of what the data is and is there is any logic in splitting the text into 6 different fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to export data in excel then use text to column command. After extracting data into separates columns (Have to same structure of access table) you have to import that excel file into access.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped!